# How to pass EditText.TextChanged Event to Parent?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-edittext, event-handling, user-controls

Usually I am using this code to handle the **TextChanged** from my **EditText**

```
EditText myEditText = new EditText(Context);
myEditText.TextChanged += (sender, e) => { /* do something */ };
```

Now, I defined my own **LinearLayout**, which holds an **EditText**. My question is, how can I **pass the TextChanged** event from the EditText to a method of the LinearLayout, so I can call

`MyLinearLayout.TextChanged` instead of `MyLinearLayout.editText.TextChanged`

```
public class MyLinearLayout : LinearLayout
{
    private EditText editText;

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        editText = new EditText(context);
        AddView(_editText);
    }


    // some method like this
    public event EventHandler<Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged
    {
        // just passes the _editText.TextChanged
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an EventHandler in custom LinearLayout , and invoke it when EditText's TextChanged evented been invoked

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
namespace App11
{
    public class MyLinearLayout : LinearLayout
    {
        private EditText editText;               

        public MyLinearLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            editText = new EditText(context);

            editText.TextChanged += EditText_TextChanged;

            AddView(editText, LayoutParameters);
        }



        private void EditText_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextChanged.Invoke(this, e);
        }


        public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;
    }
}
```

```
MyLinearLayout myLinearLayout = FindViewById<MyLinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myLinearLayout);
myLinearLayout.TextChanged += MyLinearLayout_TextChanged;

private void MyLinearLayout_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Text);
}
```

Comment: maybe you can add `if(TextChanged != null)` in `EditText_TextChanged`, since you are not forced to set the TextChanged event  ;)